# DD/MM/YYYY input validation

Tags: c++, linux, date, validation

I am working on a `date validation` (MM/DD/YYYY) and getting this error:

> *error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment*

at line:9 (`if ( Y%4=0 ) { return true; }`) running this piece of code?

```
bool valDate( int M, int D, int Y ) 
{
    if (! (1<=M and M<=12) ) return false;    
    if (! (1<=D and D<=31) ) return false;
    if ( (D==31) and (M==2 or M==4 or M==6 or M==9 or M==11) )        
        return false;
    if ( (D==30) and (M==2) ) return false;
    if ( (M==2) and (D==29) ) { 
        if ( Y%4=0 ) { return true; }        
        else { return false; }        
        if ( (Y%100==0) and (Y%400==0) ) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }   
}
```

Can anyone explain the error (and what's I'm doing wrong) please? Cheers!!

Comment: @tmpearce: In modern versions of C++, `and` and `or` are valid keywords, different ways to spell `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @GregHewgill Ah, nice - are those short-circuit? I should think about upgrading compilers at some point I suppose.

Comment: They are literally just different ways to spell `&&` and `||`. Even if your compiler doesn't support them (which I would find surprising), `#include <ciso646>` should see you right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    if ( Y%4=0 ) { return true; }
```

Should be:

```
    if ( Y%4==0 ) { return true; }
```

An lvalue is an expression that refers to some location in memory. Y%4 is an rvalue -- it cannot be assigned to, semantically speaking.

Comment: Oh yes! silly me, totally overlooked. Thanks! Still interested to know what exactly that error message signify. Cheers!!

Comment: The left operand of the assignment was Y%4, which is an r-value -- it belongs on the right of an assignment operator. An l-value is some expression that refers to a location in memory (e.g., a variable, pointer or reference).

Comment: @MacUsers: The error message means that you're trying to *assign* something (remember that `=` mean assignment) to `Y%4`. Since `Y%4` is the result of a calculation, it's called an "rvalue" (right-hand value) in C++. When you're assigning to something, you need an "lvalue" (left-hand value) on the left hand side of the assignment.